# how do I have alternating background colors for a table?

Tags: tables

I have the following table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
this row should be blue & \\
this row should be red & \\
%% these rows alternate between green and yellow
a & b \\
c & d \\
e & f \\
f & g
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and I would like to have different background colors for the cells, as mentioned in the table. Any ideas?

Comment: And maybe `\cellcolor` for the single cell's background.

Answer (score -1):

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\rowcolor{blue}
```

...`\\`

```
\rowcolor{red}
```

...

Comment: That's a very bad solution, because the alternating aspect is done better by automation (I linked an answer under the question). Please make your answer a real answer by also explaining what you did.

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks may be of interests.